# Run Nim code at compile time

Tags: dry, compile-time, nim-lang

So I know that if I define a `const` Nim will evaluate whatever I assign to it at compile time, so I could do something like this:

```
proc compileTimeCode: bool =
  # Put code here
  return true

const _ = compileTimeCode()
```

and then I could put my code in the `compileTimeCode` proc.

This works, but seems messy, overcomplicated and unintuitive. It also requires more typing than it should, and is difficult to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's the question? If there is a better way to run code at compile time?

```
static:
  # Put code here
```

[Reference](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#statements-and-expressions-static-statementslashexpression)