# How to echo/print at compile time in Nim?

Tags: compile-time, nim-lang

When working on compile time features it would be nice to `echo` something at compile time. If an `echo` is withing a macro it is already executed at compile time. But is it also possible to print something at compile time e.g. from the global scope? I'm looking for a function like `echoStatic` in this:

```nim
echoStatic "Compiling 1. set of macros..."

# some macro definitions

echoStatic "Compiling 2. set of macros..."

# more macro definitions
```

Comment: Just a self-documenting question, because I keep forgetting the solution...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need for a special `echoStatic`. This is solved by the general solution of [running code at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34712044/1804173), which is to use a `static` block:

```nim
static:
  echo "Compiling 1. set of macros..."

# some macro definitions

static:
  echo "Compiling 2. set of macros..."

# more macro definitions
```

Answer (score 1):

In languages like C, C++ and D, you can typically use a *pragma* for this job. This also works for Nim:

```js
from strformat import `&`

const x = 3
{. hint: &"{$typeof(x)} x = {x}" .}  # <file location> Hint: int x = 3
```

It also prints the file, the line and the column which can be useful for compile-time debugging.